# Google Cloud : Zone resource pool exhausted

Tags: gcloud

I am trying to deploy a ray cluster using an xml file on google cloud. But, I am getting 'ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED' error. I have tried in different zones and regions. The results are the same. Could someone help me to resolve this issue?

Here is my config.yaml file,

```
# config.yaml
cluster_name: minimal

provider:
  type: gcp
  region: europe-west4
  availability_zone: europe-west4-a # change zone if zone resource pool is exhausted
  project_id: project-xxx # Add your GCP project ID here
  min_workers: 1
  max_workers: 4
  min_workers_python: "3.10.12"  # Specify the Python version for minimum workers
  max_workers_python: "3.10.12"  # Specify the Python version for maximum workers
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you are having is that you encountered a temporary out of stock issue of the resources in the zone that you are trying to deploy, one of the the recommended workaround is what you have done which is trying a different zone. Though this is only temporary, there is no estimated time when it will have a stock soon.

Let me share with you this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-resource-availability#reasons-recommendations) wherein there are other recommendations that you can do to deploy these resources. I hope the link shared can help you deploy your resources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After trying so many zones, I found one in US.